# Unexpected character '@' (1:0) on Gatsby after installing package

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

Basically I am getting this list of errors after installing `react-awesome-query-builder` package on a brand new installed Gatsby environment.

[image]

The examples to this solution, point to add some configuration to the webpack.config.js, but on Gatsby not sure where I can add the fixes. If someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a way to add custom webpack config settings in Gatsby, this issue might be solvable by adding Gatsby packages for less and ant design ([gatsby-plugin-antd](https://github.com/bskimball/gatsby-plugin-antd), and [gatsby-plugin-less](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-less/)).

`npm install --save antd gatsby-plugin-antd less gatsby-plugin-less`

You will also need to add them into your gatsby-config.js file:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-antd",
    options: {
      style: true,
    },
  },
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-less",
    options: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
    },
  }
]
```

Each of them have additional configurations you can add in. For gatsby-plugin-antd, you'll want `style` set to true since it is using less.

For the gatsby-plugin-less package, the options will pass through to less-loader configuration. It seemed like JS being enabled was needed for `react-awesome-query-builder` to run, which is deprecated. I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid having that on.

I think that should get you past that specific webpack error, I'm not sure if it will make the `react-awesome-query-builder` demo/example work though.

If you do end up needing to edit the webpack config, you can follow the [guide on gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/).